# Socket TCP connection in different servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

I would like to know if is possible create a socket connection using TCP protocol between servers.

For example: I have two servers, one is a API, and the other only services, so the API calls the service, how could i send messages if they aren't in the same machine?

I'm using [ZeroMQ](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node) and i definitely need this separation.

Other import piece is about secure. Is TCP socket connections secure??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is absolutely possible, and is the base for the internet.  Your browser on your machine opens up sockets to remote servers perpetually.

There are so many ways to lock down TCP connections: spanning Network Level, OS level, or application level.

If you need to encrypt the data you are sending TLS/SSL is the defacto way,  if your servers are on your own private subnet with no access to the outside, unencrypted communication is often used.

I've never used ZeroMQ, but if you are using it as a central store or message bus accross your services, you could bind it to an interface with the appropriate visibilty on your net, then connect to it from any of your servers.

Since it is 100% possible, I feel liek the issues become:

**How should you expose their external interfaces?**, on which level of abstraction should you expose your servers? ie.

- Should they communicate through raw sockets?
- Should they communicate through RPC?
- Should they have a higher level interace like REST?
- Should all communcation take place through a zeroMQ?

I would highly recommend whatever course you decide to take, you audit the security very careful and make sure that nothing is exposed to the outside world that shouldn't be.

Comment: Hei @dm03514, thanks for your reply. But.. can you answer me one more thing? How one server can recognize the other? For example, machine A wants to connect in machine B with TCP, do i need use a domain, ip or something like that? Because now i'm using one machine, and i can connect using the localhost IP.

Comment: yes, some sort of naming convention, DNS is probably most flexible as it will allow you to name your resources, and have your application refer to names without having to refer to specific machines,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Redis](http://redis.io) for this purpose. If two servers (one is API and other you called as services) has to communicate other than API calls(client side). Then [Redis pub/sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) is good suggestion. 
[image]

**If they are not in same server**
yes It can communicate within a machine or remotely.Depends upon how you configure it.

**TCP Secure Socket**
yes it can be configure to use SSL see [Redis Encryption](http://redis.io/topics/encryption).

Here is great topic about this how to communicate via redis. see [Real time communication over redis](http://code.flickr.net/2012/12/12/highly-available-real-time-notifications/)